# Selecting string literal type for template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use template specialization so that I can have specialized behavior for different types.  However, I'm unable to get a template specialization for a string literal type (`const char[N]`) to bind to the specialized template.

I have a simple template `select_type<T>`, with the following specializations:

```
template <class T>
struct select_type
{
    static void action()
    {
        cout << "Generic type" << endl;
    }
};

template <>
struct select_type<std::string>
{
    static void action()
    {
        cout << "Specialization for string" << endl;
    }
};

template <std::size_t N>
struct select_type<const char[N]>
{
    static void action()
    {
        cout << "Specialization for const char array" << endl;
    }
};
```

When I attempt to instantiate each specialization as follows:

```
select_type<int>::action();
select_type<std::string>::action();
select_type<decltype("abc")>::action();
```

... I get the following output:

```
Generic type
Specialization for string
Generic type
```

Note that the specialization for `char` arrays is not invoked, even though `decltype(abc)` should produce the type `const char[4]`.

I thought that perhaps some type of type decay was occurring, so I added in a specialization for `const char*`, but it still wasn't selected.

So, why does the expression:

```
select_type<decltype("abc")>::action();
```

fail to invoke the specialization for `const char[N]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing this behavior because of how `decltype` deduces the type. String literals are lvalues. From [expr.prim.general]/p1:

> A string literal is an lvalue; all other literals are prvalues.

`decltype()` returns an lvalue-reference type for lvalues. [dcl.type.simple]/p4

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> (4.1) — if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names a set of overloaded functions,
>   the program is ill-formed;
>
> (4.2) — otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
>
> (4.3) — **otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;**
>
> (4.4) — otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.

So your specialization needs to be as follows:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct select_type<const char (&)[N]>
```