# Variadic template function name lookup fails to find specializations

Tags: c++, string, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am attempting to program a string concatenation function which utilizes my 3D library's string conversion functions, implemented with a variadic template.

The library's conversion function behaves unusually if a string (either const char[] literal or std::string) is passed to it. as it does not actually possess functions for those types, so I want to specialize the template to pull those out and not run them through the converter. Optimization would be a good reason even if the converter handled them.

```
template<typename T>
inline String c(T a)
{
    return Ogre::StringConverter::toString( a );
}
template<>
inline String c(String s)
{
    return s;
}
template<>
inline String c(const char s[])
{
    return s;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
inline String c(T a, Args... args)
{
    return Ogre::StringConverter::toString( a ) + c(args...);
}
template<typename... Args>
inline String c(String s, Args... args)
{
    return s + c(args...);
}
template<typename... Args>
inline String c( const char s[], Args... args)
{
    return s + c(args...);
}
```

However, when I compile my program, string literals sometimes fall through the const char[] specialization and are handled by the base, unspecialized template. The command:

```
U::c( "This is dMap[500][500]: ", dMap[500][500], " and this is 5: ", 5, "." )
```

returns

> This is dMap[500][500]: 112true5.

"true" being what toString returns if a string literal is passed to it. Debugging confirms that the second string literal is caught by the generic `String c(T a, Args... args)`, but not the first or third, which are handled by the specialization.

This seems related to the problem mentioned in [Selecting string literal type for template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265984/selecting-string-literal-type-for-template-specialization), but changing my template parameter declaration match those suggested in that solution, `inline String c( const char (&s) [N], Args... args )`, cause the first parameter to be caught by the specialized template, but not the second or third. Something unusual is happening here and I cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: Name lookup problems. In particular, when the first (general) variadic version is defined, the later two overloads are not in scope, and unqualified lookup for `c` will not consider them. Declare them all, and then define them.

Comment: Incidentally, the single-argument version for `String` and `const char *` should not be specializations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
inline String c(T a, Args... args)
{
    return Ogre::StringConverter::toString( a ) + c(args...);
}
```

unqualified name lookup for `c` in `c(args...)` is performed in the template definition context, which means that it only finds overloads of `c` declared up to this point, and will not find your later `c` overloads. (ADL is performed using both the definition and the instantiation contexts, but in your case it looks like there's no ADL.)

Declare them all first:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
inline String c(T a, Args... args);
template<typename... Args>
inline String c(String s, Args... args);
template<typename... Args>
inline String c( const char s[], Args... args);
```

before you define them, so that all three overloads can be found.

---

Incidentally, you should not use specializations for the single-argument case. Delete the `template<>` and use overloads instead. As written right now, `U::c("");` will not behave the way you want it to.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d4725640d1bae9a).

Comment: That fixed the issue. You're right about the single argument ones as well, I think I was stuck in the template mindset and failed to realize those weren't quite right. Thanks a lot, it makes sense and works properly now.